# Transaction scope between RabbitMQ publish and MSSQL transactions using .NET client

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm introducing RabbitMQ in .NET application, would like to be able to publish message only if database transaction succeeds, and vice-a-versa if message publish throws exception, data in database shouldn't be saved.
As I understand there's something similar in Java Spring and it's called "RabbitTransactionManager", I wonder, if there are any .NET alternatives?

Initial plan was to use TxSelect/TxCommit/TxRollback methods of RabbitMQ .NET client.
In my understanding most common solution is to wrap message publish into SQL transaction scope in code, but in that case message may be published but data not saved.

I have found article, where some techniques to solve the problem are described:
https://blogmilind.wordpress.com/2017/11/20/send-message-in-transaction/

But maybe there is more elegant, or out of the box approach?